# VB.net use a where condidition of Between Dates to open Report

Tags: vb.net, vba, ms-access-2016

I want in a form to be able to select the between dates for the filter of a report in the between Start_Date and End_Date.

this is the code I have so far.

```
Try
        Dim acc_App As Object
        acc_App = CreateObject("Access.Application")
        acc_App.OpenCurrentDatabase(programpath, True)
        Dim strCriteria As String
        strCriteria = "Start_Date >= #" & datePicker.Text &
    "# And End_Date < #" & DateTimePicker1.Text & "#"
        lblPrueba.Text = strCriteria
        acc_App.visible = True
        acc_App.DoCmd.OpenReport("HorasTrabajadas", 2, WhereCondition:=strCriteria)
    Catch Ex As Exception

        MessageBox.Show(Ex.Message)

    End Try
End Sub
```

My problem is that even getting the data from the datetimepicker it will then again ask me this parameters on access when it will open the report. 
I need some help. Thanks.

Comment: Firstly, that is brittle code to create the criteria string.  It requires that your `DateTimePickers` be using a specific date format. Better to do this: `Dim strCriteria = $"Start_Date >= #{datePicker.Value:M/dd/yyyy}# And End_Date < #{DateTimePicker1.Value:M/dd/yyyy}#"`. That will work regardless of system or application date formats.

Comment: As for your question, if you have built parameters into the report then it is going ask for those parameter values. If you want the report to simply display all the data retrieved by the query provided then you would need to not have any parameters built into the report. I don't use Access for reporting so I can't be more specific.

Comment: it still asks again when opening the file the values

Comment: What do you mean "still"? I didn't suggest that it wouldn't unless you actually change the report. If the report is written to prompt then it will prompt and if it's not then it won't.

Comment: I removed the criteria from the report, so that it gets the criteria from code. But when it opens access I have to input the Start and End Date. I want it, to get this values from the datepickers and not to enter then manually.

Comment: Edit your question and post your query for the report - it sounds like you have some fields in your report or in your filter that are not in your report's query

Answer (score 0):

User Following code

```
Try


   Dim acc_App As Object
    acc_App = CreateObject("Access.Application")
    acc_App.OpenCurrentDatabase(programpath, True)
    Dim strCriteria As String
    strCriteria = "Start_Date >= #"& datePicker.value.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd") & "# And End_Date < #" & DateTimePicker1.value.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd") & "#"
    lblPrueba.Text = strCriteria
    acc_App.visible = True
    acc_App.DoCmd.OpenReport("HorasTrabajadas", 2, WhereCondition:=strCriteria)
Catch Ex As Exception

    MessageBox.Show(Ex.Message)

End Try
End Sub
```

**"yyyy-MM-dd"** is the format of date time you can use date format as per your requirement.

Comment: it still does not work, It will just ask again when it opens access, and it is not getting any data on the report.